# How can I change host header in angular application

Tags: javascript, angular

I am having vulnerability related issue and to fix this I should use the SERVER_NAME instead of the Host header,Can I do it via angular

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: A vulnerability where you've been told to use the SERVER_NAME instead of a Host header sounds like a report about a vulnerability with some PHP code and not with client-side code at all.

Answer (score 0):

No.

The host header cannot be changed by client-side JS; it is one of the [forbidden header names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name). Its value is determined automatically based on the URL you request.